# Python - Having some trouble with raw_input()

Tags: python, raw-input

So I have been working on a two player "guess the number" program.
But im just having trouble with one thing.

So here's code:

```
import time
import random
thenumber = random.randint(1, 10)
print "Welcome to Noah's Two Player guess a number game."
print "What is player one's name?"
player1 = raw_input()
print "What is player two's name?"
player2 = raw_input()
print "Well " + player1 + " and " + player2 + ", are you ready to play?"
choice = raw_input()
if choice == yes:
    print player1 + ", pick a number from 1 to 10."
    player1guess = raw_input()

    print player2 + ", pick a number from 1 to 10."
    player2guess = raw_input()

    print "Calculating..."
    time.sleep(3)

    p1 = thenumber - player1guess
    p2 = thenumber - player2guess

    if p1 > p2:
        print player1 + " won!"

    elif p2 > p1:
        print player2 + " won!"
```

Everything is running smoothly until I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Script 1", line 11, in <module>
    if choice == yes:
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined
```

To my knowledge, I don't think I have done anything wrong, but then again I am a beginner to python.

Someone please help me with this.

EDIT: (This is python 2.7 if it makes a difference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you need quotes around `yes` : `choice =='yes'` , otherwise python will think that `yes` is a variable.

Answer (score 2):

try `if choice == 'yes':`. You're comparing it with a symbol that isn't defined.

Note there are no 'variables' in Python, only symbols and their values(with their types internally understood by the language interpreter). Think of them as names you give to various objects. They're all symbols.

Comment: "There are no variables in Python" is silly and confusing misinformation.

Comment: @NedBatchelder its not silly. Variables come with a type. Symbols are dynamically typed. There is obviously a difference.

Comment: Variables in Python don't come with a type.  You're assuming that the word "variable" means just one thing.  It means different things in different languages.  A better statement is: "Variables in Python are just names that can refer to values."